# Overlapping surfaces with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

Basically I have two graphs and I want to plot them both without overlapping one over the other.

```
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X = np.arange(0, 5, 0.05)
Y = np.arange(0, 5, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = (np.sin(X) / X) + 2
X1 = np.arange(0, 5, 0.05)
Y1 = np.arange(0, 5, 0.05)
X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(X1, Y1)
Z1 = (X / X) + 1
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha = 1, rstride=10, cstride=10, cmap=cm.autumn,linewidth=0.5, antialiased=True, zorder = 0.3)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1, alpha = 1, rstride=10, cstride=10, cmap=cm.winter, linewidth=0.5, antialiased=True, zorder = 0.5)


plt.show()
```

We can see here that we have two graphs However when viewed at 90 degrees

[image: Image of my problem]

Why does this happen and how to proceed?

Comment: The [matplotlib 3D FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html) tells you the reason under "My 3D plot doesn’t look right at certain viewing angles".